# Eliminar tildes en Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

introducir el código aquí Estoy tratando de eliminar las tildes de una string que obtengo al desencriptar, buscando en google encontré que para eliminar tildes se utiliza el el método `unicodedata.normalize('NFD', string)` pero al utilizarlo no elimina las tildes, el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
import unicodedata
import gnupg
path = 'ruta del archivo encriptado'
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gpghome='~/.gnupg')
data = gpg.decrypt_file(open(path, 'rb'))
data = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', str(data))
```

cuando imprimo la variable data obtengo lo siguiente:

```
print(data)
>>> Roman GonzÃ¡lez
```

El archivo encriptado es un JSON que contiene lo siguiente:

```
{
    "name": "Roman González"
}
```

Comment: Mírate https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135707/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-reemplazar-las-letras-con-tildes-por-las-mismas-sin-tilde-pero-no-l. Si e JSON originalmente está en UTF-8 (u otra codificación) y lees el archivo en binario no olvides decodificar los datos `data.decode("utf-8")`.

Comment: antes de encriptar los datos los codifique con utf-8 y al utilizar `data.decode('utf-8')`, como sugieres, me da el siguiente error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: intentalo hacer algo como `str(data).decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 2):

Cuando *imprimes*, la terminal se apaña para juntar los dos caracteres unicode que representan ahora a la `a con tilde`. Si lo compruebas, verás que son dos caracteres, por lo que sólo te tienes que quedar con el primero:

```
def normalize(c):
    return unicodedata.normalize("NFD",c)[0]

data = ''.join(normalize(c) for c in str(data))
```

Otra posible solución para eliminar los caracteres sobrantes sería ignorarlos:

```
data = unicode.normalize("NFD",str(data))
data = data.encode("utf8").decode("ascii","ignore")
```

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco mas encontré la solución, había que codificar la cadena con `raw_unicode_escape` y luego decodificarla con `utf-8`

```
data.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')
```

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267019/double-decoding-unicode-in-python

Comment: en ralidad alli esta la tilde solo que codificado utf8

Comment: A juzgar por tu respuesta, no querías eliminar tildes, sino "sanear" una cadena recibida que supuestamente debería llevar tildes pero en cambio trae caracteres "raros", debido a una _doble codificación_. Tal vez deberías cambiar la pregunta entonces, para no llamar a engaño a otros usuarios que busquen como quitar las tildes de la cadena.