# Función para quitar tildes python

Tags: python

Estoy empezando a programar y he querido crear una función para que reemplace todas las "í" por "i", por supuesto no me ha funcionado. ¿Me podríais decir una función sencilla para hacerlo?

Esto es lo que había intentado:

```
pregunta = input("¿El número es mayor que 50?\n").lower()

def removerTildes(cadena):
    return cadena.replace("í", "i")

removerTildes(pregunta)
print("La respuesta es", pregunta)
```

Comment: En Python las cadenas son inmutables, así que las funciones que operan en ellas suelen devolver una nueva cadena. Para ver el cambio deberias asignarle el resultado de `removerTildes(pregunta)` a `pregunta`, así: `pregunta = removerTildes(pregunta)`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar tildes en Python 3.6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150564/eliminar-tildes-en-python-3-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en que no reescribiste la variable pregunta. Así quedaría:

```
pregunta = input("¿El número es mayor que 50?\n").lower()

def removerTildes(cadena):
    return cadena.replace("í", "i")

pregunta = removerTildes(pregunta)
print("La respuesta es", pregunta)
```

Comment: Además para completar esta pregunta, si quieres remover todas las tildes, puesdes instalar el paquete ```unidecode``` con ```pip install unidecode```. Luego puedes importarlos y aplicarlo a un string ```from unidecode import unidecode  


unidecode('María vio un camión")```