# Python, QRegExp, letra "ñ" y vocales con tilde

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy realizando validaciones en diversos lineEdits, y en uno necesito poder permitirle al usuario ingresar vocales con tilde, y la letra "ñ".
Que debería agregar a mi línea de código para realizar dicha tarea?

```py
letras_espacio = QRegExp("[A-Za-z_ ]+")
```

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes coger ideas majas de [¿Cómo puedo reemplazar las letras con tildes por las mismas sin tilde, pero no la “ñ”?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/135707/83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahí está la solución. Añadí la Ñ y las diferentes vocales acentuadas (en mayúsculas y minúsculas) a la expresión regular:

```py
letras_espacio = QRegExp("[A-Za-z_ÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú ]+")
```

Comment: Por curiosidad, puedes probar si te funciona esta: `r"(?u:[\w ]+)"`  Si funciona sería más genérica, pues admitiría otros caracteres alfanuméricos válidos como èàêâô etc. Aunque igual por eso mismo no te sirve, pues esos caracteres no son válidos en español...