# ¿Como remplazar letras con acentos por las mismas sin acento?

Tags: regex, sqlite, flutter, dart

Estoy intentando realizar un método de ordenamiento basado en ciertos criterios, uno de ellos es por la primera letra con la que inicia un titulo.
Pero me topo con los **acentos** los cuales no se como evaluar con una expresión regular.

par mi método de ordenamiento primero elimino todo titulo que contenga al inicio un carácter que no sea letra o numero.

**Los títulos ya vienen ordenados desde una consulta con `SQLite` utilizando el `ORDER BY`**

```
if (titulo.contains(RegExp(r'^\W'))) {
    print(titulo);
}
```

El cual también me imprime los que inician con **acento**,

> ```
> I/flutter (12242): ¡Cuánto me ama ! 
> I/flutter (12242): Él corazón 
> I/flutter (12242): Óyenos
> ```

Intente realizar lo que sugieren en la siguiente [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/139811/76401).
pero no logre hacer que funcionara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para suerte ya existe un package que hace todo el trabajo, se llama `diacritic`, lo puedes encontrar aquí : https://pub.dev/packages/diacritic#-readme-tab-

Y si quieres ver la cantidad expresiones regulares que usa, solo revisa el código fuente: 
 https://github.com/agilord/diacritic/blob/master/lib/src/replacement_map.dart

Luego de eso, el uso es sencillo, lo agregas en el `pubspec.yaml` y aquí un ejemplo de uso:

```dart
import 'package:diacritic/diacritic.dart';

    print(removeDiacritics('¡Cuánto me ama !'));
    print(removeDiacritics('Él corazón '));
    print(removeDiacritics('Óyenos'));
```

Resultado

```
flutter: ¡Cuanto me ama !
flutter: El corazon
flutter: Oyenos
```