# comparar dos listas de excel en python

Tags: python, excel

tengo dos listas de nombres en excel y quiero compararlas en un programa en python, pero una lista contiene a los nombres en mayusculas y la otra en minusculas y con acentos, entonces al momento de comparar las listas esas diferencias no me hacen valida el parecido de los nombres y no se que hacer porque quiero modificar una lista y ponerla en mayusculas para que me compare los nombres y me di

Comment: Por favor, añade el código de lo que hasta el momento llevas

Comment: pegue el excel en un txt,porque tampoco pude manejar el excel desde pyton

Comment: almacen1 = open('dosis1.txt', 'r')
nofoto = open('dosis2.txt', 'r')


 
lista1 = []
lista2 = []
final = []
 
for line in almacen1:
    lista1.append(line)
     
for line in nofoto:
    lista2.append(line)
     
for i in lista1:
    if i in lista2:
        final.append('Si')
    else:
        final.append('No')
 
open("existe1.txt", "w").write("\n".join(("".join(item))              for item in final))
for item in lista2:
    if item in lista1:
        print (item + ' Está repetido')
    else:
        print (item + ' Es nuevo')

Comment: Puedes revisar esta opción https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135707/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-reemplazar-las-letras-con-tildes-por-las-mismas-sin-tilde-pero-no-l

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta añadiendo el código que has puesto en los comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la librería `unidecode`, para quitar acentos y simbolos, y `.lower()` para hacer todo minúsculas.

```
from unidecode import unidecode

#Creo un dataframe aleatorio
synthetic_df = pd.DataFrame(['camión', 'España', 'Andres', 'Santiago de Chile', 'fácil', 'rápido'], columns=['palabras'])

#Selecciono la columna palabras y mapeo unidecode a todas las filas, después transformo
# a string y los hago minusculas
synthetic_df.palabras.map(unidecode).str.lower()
```