# ¿Cómo cambio las letras acentuadas por letras sin tilde?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Busco cambiar las letras acentuadas por letras sin tilde. Me da error name 'Á' is not defined. ¿Cuál es la expresión regular correcta para cambiar vocales con acentos por vocales sin?

```
    def cambiar_acentos(texto_m_sp):
            """La función cambiar_acentos recibe la variable texto_m_sp, cambia las letras acentuada por letras sin acento y retorna el texto sin tildes"""
            lista = []
            lista.append(texto_m_sp)
            texto_m_sp_a = re.sub([Á-Ú]|[á-ú], [A-U]|[a-u], texto_m_sp)
            return texto_m_sp_a
        
        print(cambiar_acentos(texto_m_sp))
```

He intentado también esto otro pero me aparece esto en [aeiou]frica en vez de cambiar la vocal acentuada por la vocal sin tilde.

```
def cambiar_acentos(texto_m_sp):
    """La función cambiar_acentos recibe la variable texto_m_sp, cambia las letras acentuadas por letras sin acento y retorna el texto sin tildes"""
    lista = []
    lista.append(texto_m_sp)
    texto_m_sp_a = re.sub("[áéíóú]", "[aeiou]", texto_m_sp)
    return texto_m_sp_a

print(cambiar_acentos(texto_m_sp))
```

Comment: Por favor confirma la indentación de tu código y edita la pregunta. Así como está se va a comportar... raro. Igual, en python es necesario que seas estricto con este aspecto y no sabemos si como lo presentas es a propósito o resultado de pegar el código acá

Comment: Revisa la respuesta a tu pregunta anterior, revisa cómo se definen las expresiones regulares a usar y verás que deben ser cadenas. Por supuesto que Á no está definido porque se lo estás pasando como variable...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo reemplazar las letras con tildes por las mismas sin tilde, pero no la "ñ"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135707/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-reemplazar-las-letras-con-tildes-por-las-mismas-sin-tilde-pero-no-l)

Answer (score 0):

me he interesado por su pregunta y la he resuelto a mano, presento aquí el código:

```py
def cambiar_acentos(texto_m_sp, i):
        #pasamos el string a una lista
        lista = list(texto_m_sp)
        #recorremos la lista identificando si hay alguna vocal con tilde, si la hay, esta bocal se reemplazará por esa misma vocal sin tilde
        for letra in lista:
            if (letra == "á"):
                lista[i] = "a"
    
            elif (letra == "é"):
                lista[i] = "e"
            
            elif (letra == "í"):
                lista[i] = "i"
            
            elif (letra == "ó"):
                lista[i] = "o"
            
            elif (letra == "ú"):
                lista[i] = "u"
            i += 1
        texto_m_sp = "".join(lista) #Aquí asignamos la lista convertida a string a la variable que contiene el texto con las vocales acentuadas
        return texto_m_sp #retornamos el texto
        
#variable para reconocer el indice de los elementos en la listan     
i = 0

#texto que introduce el usuario
texto_m_sp = input(">> ")

#se convierte el texto en mayúsculas a minúsculas para no diferenciar entre vocales acentuadas mayúsculaso minúsculas
texto_m_sp = texto_m_sp.lower()

#imprimimos el return de la funciñon
print(cambiar_acentos(texto_m_sp, i))
```

Resultado del código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte servido de ayuda

¡Un saludo!