# Eliminar tildes pero mantener ñ

Tags: python

Necesito utilizando unicamente unidecode eliminar las tildes de una cadena de texto y conserva las ñ.
Sé que se puede hacer utilizando unicodedata, sin embargo necesito hacer toda esta gestión solo utilizando unidecode, es posible realizarlo?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo reemplazar las letras con tildes por las mismas sin tilde, pero no la "ñ"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135707/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-reemplazar-las-letras-con-tildes-por-las-mismas-sin-tilde-pero-no-l)

Comment: Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Siempre preguntar debe ser tu último recurso: primero busca, investiga, y verifica que en el sitio no se hayan hecho preguntas similares.

Comment: Mirando unidecode, no parece exponer ninguna forma de modificar las tablas de sustitución. Puedes conseguirlo (aparte de modificando las tablas de traducción en el código fuente del modulo) de dos formas; obteniendo las eñes de de la cadena y restituyendolas una vez pasa la cadena por unidecode o directmente evitar que las eñes pasen por unidecode pasándole solo rebanados o caracteres que excluyan las eñes y luego reconstruir la cadena. Sea como sea sera horriblemente ineficiente comparado con usar otras alternativas a unidecode.

Comment: Si a pesar de todo es imprescindible que uses unidecode, la pregunta enlazada como duplicado no te va a servir (aunque muestra opciones mucho mas eficientes y usando la biblioteca estándar). En tal caso intenta resolverlo y si te atascas edita la pregunta agregando el codigo que estas intentando y el problema/error concreto que tienes para que la pregunta cumpla con los criterios del sitio y podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Ya lo he conseguido gracias @FJSevilla perdona pero soy bastante nuevo en esto y no daba con la solución : D

Comment: Y gracias @padaleiana, antes de escribir esta pregunta ya había mirado ese foro pero su respuesta no me sirve ya que no utiliza unidecode. De todas formas muchas gracias por intentar ayudar y si te interesa ya esta la solución publicada por si le quieres echar un vistazo. Un saludo : D

Comment: Hola de nuevo @FJSevilla ya he subido una solución con el código actualizado por si quieres echarle un vistazo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola de nuevo acabo de subir una solución con el código actualizado

```
import re

from unidecode import unidecode
def quitar_tildes_y_preservar_n(texto):
    parts = re.split(r'([ñÑ])', texto)
    texto_sin_tildes = ''.join([(unidecode(x) if x != 'ñ' and x != 'Ñ' else x) for x in parts])
    return texto_sin_tildes
cadena_original = "Me encantá Logroño"
cadena_sin_tildes = quitar_tildes_y_preservar_n(cadena_original)
print(cadena_sin_tildes)
```

Comment: Claro que soy el mismo usuario jajaja

Comment: Pero no se pq no me deja comentar arriba ya que me dice que tengo que tener al menos 50 de reputación no se si es un error del sitio web en particular

Comment: Si  hice el formulario pero todavia no me han respondido jaja

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado @padaleiana, y ya he subido la solución a la pregunta por si te interesa. Gracias : D

Comment: Ahora si es correcta, solo una observación, puedes eliminar la lista intermedia y pesarle a `join` el generador directamente, es mas eficiente tanto en términos de CPU como de memoria, es decir: `''.join((unidecode(x) if x != 'ñ' and x != 'Ñ' else x) for x in parts)`, aunque para cadenas pequeñas la diferencia no sera muy apreciable.

Comment: En otro tema, en principio las respuestas no deben ser solo código,  te recomiendo que siempre y añadas una pequeña explicación de como funciona tu código (por ejemplo, en este caso la expresión regular y la importancia del grupo de captura), eso puede ayudar a otros usuarios a entenderlo y a adaptarlo a sus problemas concretos y la respuesta sera mejor recibida.  Por otro lado, es totalmente correcto y de agradecer que respondas a tus propias preguntas y compartas tu solución. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla. Un abrazo : D